# How can I add a timestamp to every line in a piped log output?

Tags: php, logging, cron

I have to run some rather lengthy and legacy PHP scripts using cron. I want to capture the pid,  output (both std and err) and log it to a file, but I would also like every line of this output to be timestamped. These scripts are quite fragile and it is not viable to properly instrument them with logging.

I came up with a bit of bash + gawk script that accomplishes this like so:

```sh
# run php in a subshell, capturing the PID and redirecting the output.
(php $@ 2>&1 & echo $! >&3) 3> $PID_FILE | gawk \
    -v php_pid=$(while ! test -s $PID_FILE; do sleep .1; done; cat $PID_FILE) \
    '{ print "[" php_pid strftime(" %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S] "), $0 }' \
    >> $LOG_FILE
```

This works OK, however, it's a rather convoluted and obscure solution to an otherwise simple problem.

Is there a simpler, better solution or tool to accomplish this?

Comment: Maybe take a look into [ts](https://linux.die.net/man/1/ts)

Comment: It's a good pointer, but the script would end up looking pretty much the same (same PID capture method and a format string containing the PID)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## an actual alternative -

Let `awk` handle the wait.

```
mkfifo pipe_name           # a FIFO as a tempfile for un-timestamped data
php $@ > pipe_name 2>&1 &  # your program in background to the FIFO
echo $! > $PID_FILE        # the pid into a holding file
gawk 'BEGIN { while ( 0 == getline php_pid < "pid" ) { system("sleep .1") } }
  { print "[" php_pid strftime(" %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S] "), $0 }' pipe_name >> $LOG_FILE
rm -f pid pipe_name        # clean up
```

I don't like that this spawns a whole subshell for a tenth-second sleep, but it avoids loading another extension and having to be concerned whether this local system is above or below version 5.1... (c.f. the [manual entry](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Extension-Sample-Time) for details)

## just a rewrite

On closer inspection, this solution is riddled with problems and I don't recommend you use it.

First, it fails if the input has more than one string.

```
$: for x in one two three; do sleep 1; echo test $x; done | sed 's/^/date +"%F %T - "/e'
date: extra operand ‘one’
Try 'date --help' for more information.

date: extra operand ‘two’
Try 'date --help' for more information.

date: extra operand ‘three’
Try 'date --help' for more information.
```

I can fix that by putting the whole line into the date format:

```
$: for x in one two three; do sleep 1; echo test $x; done | sed -E 's/^(.*)/date +"%F %T - \1"/e'
2020-12-09 09:50:15 - test one
2020-12-09 09:50:16 - test two
2020-12-09 09:50:18 - test three
```

but that will corrupt any data it sees as a valid formatting directive.

```
$: for x in one two three; do sleep 1; echo "test %c $x"; done | sed -E 's/^(.*)/date +"%F %T - \1"/e'
2020-12-09 09:51:56 - test Wed, Dec 09, 2020  9:51:56 AM one
2020-12-09 09:51:57 - test Wed, Dec 09, 2020  9:51:57 AM two
2020-12-09 09:51:58 - test Wed, Dec 09, 2020  9:51:58 AM three
```

This method is really much kludgier than what you already had, as it's spawning a `date` process for every line...

Adding in the PID is the only reason it becomes problematic, and your solution for that, while visually painful, really isn't bad at all.

Taking another look... is the PID file really taking long enough to write that spawning the `gawk` reads an empty? This works fine for me:

```
$: (./tst 2>&1 & echo $! >pid ) | awk -v php_pid=$(<pid) '{
     print "[" php_pid strftime(" %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S] "), $0 }'
```

If you just want a slightly less confusing, more maintainable way to write basically the same logic -

```
{ ./tst 2>&1 & echo $! >pid; } | { declare -i val=0; until (( val )); do cnt=$(<pid); sleep .1; done; awk -v php_pid=$(<pid) '{print "[" php_pid strftime(" %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S] "), $0 }'; }
```

Switched to curly enclosure, works fine for this.

Or, using your values,

```
{ php $@ 2>&1 & echo $! > $PID_FILE; } |                 # run the job in bg, save PID
{ declare -i val=0;                                      # initialize a gatekeeper
  until (( val )); do cnt=$(<$PID_FILE); sleep .1; done; # wait till pid is loaded
  # now process  the data
  gawk -v php_pid=$(<$PID_FILE) '{ print "[" php_pid strftime(" %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S] "), $0 }' >> $LOG_FILE
}
```

## original

Pipe it through `sed` with a expression substitution.

```
$: for x in one two three; do sleep 1; echo $x; done | sed 's/^/date +"%F %T - "/e'
2020-12-04 10:26:25 - one
2020-12-04 10:26:26 - two
2020-12-04 10:26:27 - three
```

Comment: Can you think of a simple way to include the pid (of the spawned process, not the script pid) on each line? Your approach seems more elegant than the gawk one, but it'll also start getting complicated.

Comment: Yes, on a loaded machine with multiple cores, the piped (awk) process can very well run before the pid file is actually written. I tried running it in a tight while loop and it does happen from time to time.

Comment: How about `(php $@ 2>&1 & echo $! >pid; sleep .5) | gawk` ? It's simpler...

Comment: gawk could start before the subshell spawns, even with a sleep there. There is no guarantee that piped processes will start in a particular order. Of course, the standard input of gawk will be blocking until the sleep ends, but that's not when the pid file is read.

Comment: It absolutely can, and on very rare occasions will. Your system may make it more common. I won't give you any crap for being thorough, lol. Programming well is creative pedantry - that's our job. :)  I made a few edits, but all in all I still think your approach is logically sound, and probably the best solution in most cases. All I can really add is an alternate paint job.

Comment: I even had to change it to `test -s` because the pid file was being created, but was still empty at that point! Thanks for your thorough answer, I will wait to accept it as I doubt our similar solutions to this are the right ones.